# How to Ctrl + Click a filename from file links with other characters from VS Code's Console?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have file links with line numbers from stack traces in the VS Code console like so:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from my_file.rb:557:in `<main>'
        2: from my_file.rb:366:in `each'
        1: from my_file.rb:372:in `block (2 levels) in process'
my_file.rb:372:in `to_f': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) (ArgumentError)
```

When I Ctrl-Click such a link, VSCode tries to open it but returns "No Matching Result", because it sees `my_file.rb:372:in` as a link target (due to the missing space before `in`).

[image: VSCode Command Palette]

I have to manually press backspace three times to remove `:in` from the search term and press enter again.

Is there any way to teach VSCode to interpret these file links correctly?

Comment: you could file an issue that the regex that tries to match a `file.ext:line:char` is matching an impossible combi

Comment: I will do that but was hoping for an extension or setting.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136190 Let's see...

Comment: They fixed it! https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/c3be8a8cc0f1c729b160076378ac63d6054ab035

Comment: They probably could have fixed is generic, if some other tool prints a text different from `:in` they have to add another hack

Comment: They certainly should have!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with running tests for Python apps, with the terminal output showing the format `filename.py::test_name` (similar to your Ruby output), and VS Code failed to highlight/select *just* the filename.

You can try updating the setting `terminal.integrated.wordSeparators` to include the `:` character:

```json
"terminal.integrated.wordSeparators": " ()[]{}',\"`─:",  // <--- Add `:`
```

The default value doesn't include the `:` character, so I think, that's why it doesn't split `filename:xxx` into its "word" parts. Here's a demo where I try to click on `main.py` from `main.py::test_my_model`:

[image: demo effect of adding colon]

The setting was introduced in [VS Code 1.45](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_45#_control-doubleclick-word-selection):

> Control double-click word selection
>
> The new `terminal.integrated.wordSeparators` setting lets you customize the separator characters used to delimit a word when you double-click in the terminal.

In case it's version- or env-specific, it works on:

- Visual Studio Code 1.61.2
- macOS (using <kbd>CMD</kbd> + click)

Comment: This is a great find, thanks! Unfortunately it does cut off the line number as well.